# Xamarin Studio ignoring compiler options

Tags: c#, mono, portable-class-library, xamarin-studio

In `Xamarin Studio` for `Mac` I've just checked **Do not reference mscorlib.dll** under project options of my `PCL` (I'm using the `mono` implementation of `mscorlib`).

For my surprise, I've already ran the lib in different platforms and everything gone fine so far. However the `IDE` stills thinking the default `mscorlib` is there.

So things like that are happening:

```
//The default mscorlib has List
var myList = new List<int>(); 

//This method is implemented only in my custom mscorlib.
//It compiles but the IDE does not recognize the method
//Because it thinks myList uses the List implementation from the default mscorlib
myList.AsReadOnly();
```

There is someway to make the `IDE` ignore the default `mscorlib`?

Also, what are the risks of using the mono implementation of `mscorlib`? I've already created files and used a lot of utilities functions with this, so this implementation is truly multi platform?